# How can I know if its possible to unzip a file or not with wget?

Tags: bash, shell, download, zip, wget

```bash
wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834 -O temp.zip; unzip temp.zip
```

Works but what if the file I am downloading is not a zip so it needs to retain the original name and not `temp.zip`. For example instead of temp.zip its called `temp.7z` So its not possible to unzip it in bash. So if the file is 7z then do not make wget rename it to temp.zip after downloading. And I'd thought of something like this but you cant get the filename to what you download with wget.

```bash
filename = wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834
unzip filename || echo "Must be a .zip file in order to unzip it!"
```

But this obviously does not work since wget dont bother downloading the file if you have not given it a filename to save it as or a directory (i think) and will give this error:

```bash
unzip:  cannot find or open wget, wget.zip or wget.ZIP.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (...)wget dont bother downloading the file if you have not given it a
> filename to save it as or a directory (i think)(...)

This is not true, `wget` downloads file using name generated from given URL. In this particular case

```
wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834
```

download file as `download_script.php@src_id=11834`, which as you might observe is derived from part after last `/`, but rather not what you want to be. However in cases of link like this, there is often [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) tag informing web browser about name of file, as [`wget` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) informs you might use `--content-disposition` flag in order to make `wget` use it, when you do

```
wget --content-disposition http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=11834
```

file will be downloaded as `NERD_tree.zip`

Answer (score 1):

Save downloaded file with a temp name and test file type with `file` command

```
t="$(file --brief --mime-type file.tmp)"

case "$t" in
    'application/zip')
        echo "zip file"
        ;;
    'application/x-7z-compressed')
        echo "7z file"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "unknown file type"
        ;;
esac
```